# Why do my UICollectionViewCells change alpha value when animating a superview constraint change?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a superview that contains several subviews, including a UICollectionView.  The superview has a layout constraint that pins its location to the bottom of the screen.  I would like to hide the view by changing that constraint and then calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` on the UIViewController.  This works fine, EXCEPT, that the cells of the UICollectionView drop to alpha = 0 at the start of the animation and then change back to alpha = 1 by the end.

It isn't super noticeable as the animation is quick, but I don't understand why this is happening.  No other subviews have this behavior and the UICollectionView itself does not change alpha... only the cells.

To hide the superview I call:

```
entryOffset.constant = entryHeight.constant
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }) { (finished) in
}
```

With the slow speed of the animation (5 seconds) it is evident that the cells completely hide... and then fade back in.  I have broken inside:

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}`

and you can see that the cells are being reloaded (which I also don't understand since it is only the upper level constraint that has changed... not the UICollectionView itself.

Any thoughts as to why the cells' alpha values are changing and how I can prevent this?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the cells' alpha values to not change by subclassing the flow layout:

```
import UIKit

class NoFadeFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attrs?.alpha = 1.0
        return attrs
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attrs?.alpha = 1.0
        return attrs
    }

}
```